# Unable to encode or decode the string properly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, encoding, utf-8, python-2.x

I tried to look at bunch of stackoverflow examples.

Python version used: **Python 2.7.10**

Output of the string s looked like

```
u'bh\xfcghi' where \xfc=ü
```

I am reading this from a webpage.

After I encode the string via .encode('utf-8'), it looks like

```
'bh\xc3\xbcghi' where \xc3\xbc=ü
```

Expected Output should be:

```
bhüghi
```

I even tried to decode/encode(latin-1), decode(utf-8).

After  nfn neil comment I tried the following again:

elem.text output:

```
('elem text:', u'bh\xfcghi\nMCI\n8 90 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 26 41.4 18.5 89 14.9')
```

elem text type:

```
('elem text type:', <type 'unicode'>)
```

Now, I am trying to print it:

```
splitString = elem.text.encode('utf-8').decode("utf-8").split()
print("splitString: ", splitString[0])
```

SplitString[0] output:

```
u'bh\xfcghi'
```

Now if I print the whole string after split:

```
print("splitString: ", splitString)
```

SplitString output:

```
[u'bh\xfcghi', u'MCI', u'8', u'90', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'2', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'2', u'26', u'41.4', u'18.5', u'89', u'14.9']
```

Full code is in pastebin:
Here's [A link](https://pastebin.com/E3PNmCbW)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The issue is there is something happening that's making it not modify a string.  It's not an encoding issue.

Comment: [Pastebin link for the fullcode](https://pastebin.com/E3PNmCbW)

Comment: I got it working,
`
        splitString = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', elem.text).encode('ascii','ignore').split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using unicodedata library:

```
splitString = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',
elem.text).encode('ascii','ignore').split()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = u'bh\xfcghi\nMCI\n8 90 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 26 41.4 18.5 89 14.9'
s = s.encode('utf-8')
xs = s.split(' ')
print(xs[0])
```

Output:

```
bhüghi
MCI
8
```

Try it; it works. The reason you don't get your 'expected' output when just typing it at a terminal, is that Python uses \x escape codes when you don't use `print`.

Comment: this won't work, please refer to pastebin for fullcode access